Does Bitcoin Core have any monitoring support?
Does Bitcoin Core have any monitoring support? I would like to monitor my bitcoin core node.

If you want to monitor your peers, you can use a tool created by 0xB10C. Here's the link https://github.com/0xB10C/peer-observer
Also there is an article for setting up the peer-observer and visualising peers using Prometheus and Grafana https://bytecorner.dev/peer-observer-monitor-your-bitcoin-peers

Bitcoin Core doesn't have any code for Prometheus support. There is a closed issue discussing it, with links to other related discussions and potential solutions, such as USDT (User-space, Statically Defined Tracing).
